# Interference Bands and Dark contrast issues on Fujifilm FinePix S2000HD. Is it salvageable?

Tags: fujifilm, error

I am trying to figure out what is going on with this camera and if it's salvageable somehow. I have already reset it to factory settings and there's been no improvement. It only took pictures correctly when set to manual with no zoom in a bright environment.

The camera takes a very dark contrast picture on some lower light settings, while taking banded images when on lighter settings.

It also seems to make a high contrast picture regardless of setting when on macro mode

At first I thought the banding could be caused by either the lights or movement, but every picture I took was on a tripod and I managed to take banded images even under sunlight

Couldn't really find any references to this issue after searching around the internet, so I'm honestly not sure how to proceed.

Here's some reference pictures:

- ***Manual mode, no zoom. Flash. Default options:*** [image]
- ***Shutter priority AE:*** [image]
- ***Also Shutter priority AE. No settings besides shutter speed changed:***[image]

---

Basically, the camera isn't behaving as expected when taking the picture itself. None of these issues appear on the display when using the camera, which, at least to me, seems to indicate the issue is not on the camera sensor.

To me, this issue feels like a midway hardware to software issue related to light balance somehow, but I have been unable to pinpoint the cause of it.

However, there are very specific cases in which the camera actually works perfectly as intended, and I can't figure out which variables cause it.

Even reproducing with the exact same settings, I've been unable to reproduce this image quality. Attempts end up falling back into the previous two examples:

[image]

---

- Is there a way to save this camera?
- Does anyone know what could cause it?

Comment: Thanks for inlining the images. I reopened the question.